# Preprocess ONLY string constant concatenation in cpp file

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am trying to extract some string constants/literals from files, along with their line location. But sometimes, these are composited from macro definitions to get the final string. Something like:

```
do_stuff(PREFIX_STR "somename" SUFFIX_STR)
```

This will probably not be 100% foolproof even if I manage it, but I need some balance between complexity and reliability.

One way to get this done is to run compiler for those files with preprocessor only mode and read the result. The problem with that is that the result will look nothing like the original file. Again, the correct way to do this would be to analyze the AST, but that would be more work than this is worth.

I'd just like to tell the compiler "Do preprocessing only, but only resolve strings, ignore everything else". Any compiler will do, it does not have to be the same I use to build the code. So from a C++ file like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include "./my_header.h"

#define SOME_MACRO(x, y) anything could be here
#define PREFIX_STR "prefix"
void some_function()
{
    do_stuff(PREFIX_STR "somename");
    SOME_MACRO(PREFIX_STR "othername");
    do_stuff("custom_prefix" "othername");
}
```

I'd like to get a file like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include "./my_header.h"

#define SOME_MACRO(x, y) anything could be here

void some_function()
{
    do_stuff("prefixsomename");
    SOME_MACRO("prefixothername");
    do_stuff("custom_prefixothername");
}
```

I don't think I can get exactly what I want, but I'd appreciate any advice that helps me get as close as possible.

Comment: does the `-E` flag do too much?

Comment: This answer might be highly dependent on which preprocessor you are using

Comment: The only idea in my mind is to write a AWK script which reads the defines and search the results and print it. AST is far behind preprocessing, isn't it?

Comment: A project I worked on a long time ago in the 1990s used Python as a pre-pre-processor to do code generation shenanigans like this.  Worked really well.  The Python manipulation identifiers all had a `$` in the name (our own convention).

Comment: @Mestkon Any compiler/preprocessor is fine if it does what I need.

Comment: @Eljay I can't change what the names of the `#define`s are. If I could a regex based solution would work for me.

Comment: Maybe you could put together something using [Boost.Wave](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/wave/)?

Comment: If you used a pre-pre-processor strategy, you would **not** *have* to change the names.  We found it convenient to have the pre-pre-processor identifiers we used to be clearly distinguished (via naming convention) from the identifiers used for C++ code.